# Scalaで小・中規模のCodeReadingしておいた方がいいプロダクト

Tags: scala

最近、コップ本を読み進めて後半戦にさしかかろうかと思っているところなのですが、その後の展開を考えていまして、なにかちょっとした規模のプロダクトのコードを読んだ方がいいかと考えています。恐らく、規模が大きい物はSpark当たりでは無いかとは思っていますが、CLI前提で、小・中規模でおすすめのプロダクトは無いでしょうか？

Comment: CLI前提でってどういう意味なんでしょうか？ GUIやWebのアプリは除外という意味ですか？  （代理コメント https://twitter.com/scalajp_gitter/status/569761300596674562 ）

Comment: 質問ありがとうございます。はい、ご指摘の通りです。

Comment: 読む目的をはっきりさせると答えやすいかもしれません。

Comment: 回答はしましたが、この手の客観的な解を選ぶことができなさそうな質問、特に何らかの一覧を求める質問は Stackoverflow では[避けるべきとされています](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)。

Comment: kawty なるほど今度からはもう少し情報を出しやすいように気をつけてみます。

Eugane Ykota ありがとうございます。そうですね。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask　こちらの方確認致しました。
気をつけます。

Answer (score 2):

個人的に、[n8han](https://github.com/n8han) (と NY系の仲間たち) が書いたコードはコードがきれいにまとまっててセンスがあると思います。HTTP のためのライブラリ [dispatch reboot](https://github.com/dispatch/reboot) とかどうでしょう。

CLI縛りで考えると、json parsing のための [sjson](https://github.com/debasishg/sjson) などがあります。実用的には json4s (と jawn) などを使いますが、読む素材としては確か sjson が型クラスを使った例になってるはず。型クラスというパターンに影響を受けた実装になってるのが、拙著のコマンドライン・オプションの [scopt](https://github.com/scopt/scopt)（とそれに関して書いた [scopt 3.0](http://eed3si9n.com/ja/scopt3)）とか [repatch-twitter](https://github.com/eed3si9n/repatch-twitter) ([Dispatch プラグインの書き方](http://eed3si9n.com/ja/howto-write-a-dispatch-plugin)) などです。

twitter つながりでいくと、twitter社は[いくつもライブラリを公開している](https://github.com/twitter)ので、興味があるものを眺めてみるのもいいかもしれません。

他に CLI と言うとログのための [Scala Logging](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging) とか。

中規模か大規模かの区別が不明ですが、読めるようになっておくと役立つのは[標準ライブラリのコード](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/v2.11.5/src/library)と[Reflection API](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/v2.11.5/src/reflect/scala/reflect)及び[コンパイラの実装のコード](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/v2.11.5/src/compiler)です。